# How to create the custom exception/rule in eslint and prettier for ignore 'of =>' and 'returns =>' in decorators of resolver?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, eslint, prettier

### Introduction

I using NestJS and @nestjs/graphql with default eslint and prettier settings.
When I create graphql resolver, I have some problem with eslint and prettier.

### Problem

Prettier notify the error:

> Replace `returns` with `(returns)`

@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars notify like this:

> 'returns' is defined but never used

This errors make it difficult to analyze other errors.
Example the resolver code:

```
@Resolver(of => Movie)
export class MoviesResolver {
  constructor(private readonly moviesService: MoviesService) {}

  @Query(returns => [Movie])
  movies(): Promise<Movie[]> {
    return this.moviesService.findAll()
  }

  @Query(returns => Movie)
  movie(@Args('id', { type: () => String }) id: string) {
    return this.moviesService.findOneById(id)
  }

  @Mutation(returns => Movie)
  async addMovie(@Args('data') data: CreateMovieInput): Promise<Movie> {
    const movie = await this.moviesService.create(data)
    return movie
  }
}
```

I need to exception for this phrases:

```
of => 
returns =>
```

### Question

What the right way to create custom rule/exception for this errors?
I think that fix this every lines in each resolver by hands is not good and right way.

I found some docs by my query

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

But this docs didn't help.
I don't need to ignore the all resolver files or line by hand. I wanna to ignore some code by pattern may be regex

```
/of => /gm
```

and

```
/returns => /gm
```

Comment: read the options available for that rule here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#options

Comment: You could just do an anonymous arrow function with no parameters. We just use `of` and `returns` for readability. `() => ClassType`

Answer (score 0):

In .eslintrc.js add new rule in rules:

```
  '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "(returns|of)" }]
```

In .prettierrc add this:

```
"arrowParens": "avoid"
```